# Unable to locate package ubuntu-after-install

Tags: apt

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-after-install` does not work. I just installed Ubuntu, so I don't know if there's a problem with my installation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Apt Unable to locate package, you should add appropriate repository, In your case run following command: (for [`ubuntu-after-install`](https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/ubuntu-after-install))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/ubuntu-after-install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-after-install
```

To add universe, restricted and partner repository run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
```